# Why is the output a question mark in a box instead of numbers

Tags: c

I am doing a simple infix to postfix conversion program but upon inputting the resulting postfix expression, the numbers come out as question marks in boxes. What do I do to have the output be numbers?

I don't know which part of the code is causing this problem.

```
bool convert(char inf[], char post[])
{
    char term;
    int i, k, length, oprn;
    nd top;
    top = createStack();
    length = strlen(inf);
    for(i=0, k=-1; i<length; i++)
    {
        term = inf[i];
        if(isdigit(term))
        {
            oprn = term - '0';
            post[++k] = oprn;
        }
        else if (term == '(')
        {
            push(&top,term);
        }
        else if (term == ')')
        {
            bool empty;
            empty = isEmpty(top);
            while(!empty && peek(top) != '(')
                post[++k] = pop(&top);
            if(!empty && peek(top) != '(')
                return -1; //the expression is not valid
            else
                pop(&top);
        }
        else //if term is an operator
        {
            bool empty;
            empty = isEmpty(top);
            if(empty){ 
                push(&top,term);}
            else
            {
                while(!empty && prec(term)<=prec(peek(top)))
                    post[++k] = pop(&top);
                push(&top,term);    
            }
        }
    }//end of for loop
    while(!isEmpty(top))
        post[++k] = pop(&top);
    post[++k] = '\0';
}
```

I called the function using this in main

```
int main(void)
{
    bool ok;
    char inFix[s];
    char postFix[s]="";

    getInfix(inFix);
    ok = convert(inFix,postFix);
    if(ok)
    {
        printf("\n\nThe resulting postfix expression is: ");
        puts(postFix);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n\nAn error has occurred...");
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

You subtracted `term` here by '0', which means your digits are now no longer ASCII '0' to ASCII '9', but rather numeric char 0 to char 9, which corresponds to a bunch of ASCII control characters.

```
    if(isdigit(term))
    {
        oprn = term - '0';
        post[++k] = oprn;
    }
```

Comment: Replaced it with simply post[++k] = term; and it now works! Can't believe that was all it needed. Thanks for the help!